# What is the Big-O of a nested loop where internal loop iteration depends on the external loop iteration increasing as a multiple of 2?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

What is the **Big-O** time complexity of a nested loop where the iteration of the internal loop  **depends** on the iteration of the external loop and the iteration of the external loop is increasing as a **multiple of 2**?

```cpp
for (long long j = 1; j < n; j *= 2) {
    for (long long k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

I also need the **calculation**.

Comment: maybe the complexity is O(n), but i cann't prove it.

Comment: 1+2+2^2+2^3 and so on. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/how-to-prove-a-formula-for-the-sum-of-powers-of-2-by-induction O(2^n-1) should be the result.

Answer (score 2):

Detailed version of [amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67046646/4921252):

Let, [image: n=2^m]. So, [image: j={1,2,4,8,16,...,2^m}] is a geometric series. The inner loop will iterate `j` times for each value of `j`.

**Cmplexity** = the inner loop total iteration

[image: =1+2+4+8+16+...+2^m]

[image: =2^(m+1)-1]

[image: =2*2^m-1]

[image: =2*n-1]

[image: =O(n)]